# Regex: remove a single html tag from string

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I would like to know how to remove a single html tag from a string of html tag.

Here is an example of a string in JavaScript:

```
var str = "<ol class="breadcrumb>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
</ol>
<div>body</div>
<ol>
  <li>a</li>
</ol>"
```

I would like to remove the first `<ol>`. Here is what I have tried:

```
str.replace(/\<ol class=\"breadcrumb".*\<\/ol\>/, '');
```

But this solution will delete everything in the string.

I have a hunch that, rather than using `.*` in the above solution, I should match everything except `</\ol\>`. But how can I do it, and is there an alternative solution?

### Edit

I am writing a web crawler and would like to parse an HTML string.

Comment: Incoming [don't parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?rq=1) comments.

Comment: HTML is not a regular language thus can't be parsed by regular expressions.

Comment: Use JavaScript, jQuery or some DOM parser. Your life will be much simpler.

Comment: @Marty - Tony the Pony alert

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I am writing a crawler and would like to process the data by using regex. Is this a valid use case, or could you suggest an alternative approach?

Comment: @SungWonCho RegExp is mathematically insufficient to parse HTML. Use [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) instead.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Thanks. Since I am on the server side, I will use an alternative library to parse and manipulate DOM. Feel free to add it as an answer so that people who are googling this can know about it.

Comment: [Here you go](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom).

Comment: If there was <ol> tag inside of another <ol> tag. Regex cannot parse collectly end tag. This is limitation of regex. That needs to use some logic with javascript.

Comment: Or is there something limitation to be able to parse with regex in your html files? If you want to parse whole html tags correctly, maybe all tag cannot be nested with same name tag. Cuz,any language needs to count tags are not regular language.

Comment: I can not add an answer since it has been marked as a duplicate. For your specific case, it would be solved by putting a question mark after the star. So .*?  This makes the search non greedy, and stops as soon as possible instead of taking as much as possible.

Comment: @Froziph and you aren't even going to mention the issue with nesting?

Comment: @Peter-R They are not nested in his example. I said it worked for his specific case. Using regex for html isn't great, I believe all the other posts made that abundantly clear. I just wanted to introduce him to the ? operator in case he didn't know it.